# Nombre a columna en DataGrid VB6

Tags: datagrid, vb6

Estoy intentando poner nombres a cada columna en un `DataGrid` en `VB6`, este `DataGrid` no está cargado con datos. Solo quiero ponerle los nombres a las columnas el problema es el siguiente:

Actualmente, tengo este código:

```
Dim TipoNumero As String
TipoNumero = Me.DataGrid1.Columns.Items(0).Name.ToString
MsgBox (TipoNumero)
```

Pero, al momento de compilar me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Error de compilación: 

El procedimiento externo no es válido
```

En la siguiente imagen se ve donde sale el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Soluciones?

Comment: .Name.ToString no me suena a nada valido en vb6.. estas seguro que es asi?

Comment: Amigo consulta, el datagrid le agregaste las columnas o solo lo creaste? si no creaste las columnas no las podrás renombrar y si las agregaste, con la misma interfaz visual le puedes colocar nombres

Comment: Lo vi en un video de YouTube @gbianchi

Comment: Solo lo cree, ¿Cómo le agrego las columnas? @harifo

Comment: Enseguida te preparo la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias @harifo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado, para agregar las columnas a un DGV(DataGridView) existen 2 formas simples, la primera es a través de la interfaz visual, donde haces click en el DGV recien agregado y en el botón de acción que aparece en la esquina superior derecha le indicas "Agregar Columna" y ahí tienes propiedades editables como el mismo nombre, tamaño, entre otros.

La segunda forma, de manera programática; Debes iniciarlo de esta manera una vez agregada la columna:

```
With miDGV
     'Numero de columna
    .columns(0).HeaderText = "Nombre de primera columna"
end With
```

Ante cualquier duda que tengas, consulta.